# Will dehumidifier damage old painted plaster?

Tags: plaster, moisture, dehumidifier

I found a window leak during the rain, which ended up wetting a plaster wall near the window. During the rain, a 2 in by 6 in spot of paint lightly bubbled, the bubbles went away shortly after. Now, a few days after the rain my pinless moisture meter shows elevated moisture spot 1 ft by 3 ft area. I'm having the window resealed, but in the meantime I've put up a 19G dehumidifier in the room (and pointed a box fan to the spot), bringing down the humidity from 65% to 30%. Planning to run for 2-4 days total before having to return the dehumidifier.

I see many articles online cautioning against using dehumidifier to speed up plaster drying, but what about already cured (at least 10+ years) plaster walls? Should I be worried about damaging the non-wet parts by using a dehumidifier?

Comment: drywalls as the name says, like to be dry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plaster curing (from new) needs adequate moisture to complete growing crystals.

Drying already cured plaster that got wet that does not apply.